# change x,y of board by user input

Tags: c++

i have a board of 10x10 and here his code:

```
    for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++) // X
    {
         cout << 0;

         for(int y = 0; y < 10; y++) // Y
         {
             cout << " " << 0;
         }

         cout << endl;
    }
```

now I want to change `0 to 1` in the `x,y` location by user input.
how can I do that?

here is simply what I want to do ( in pictures ):
the user input is `x = 2`, `y = 2` and the table changing from Table 1 Example to Table 2 Example ( as a new table ): 
[TABLE 1 Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwTGv.png)  [| TABLE 2 Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgYr8.png)

its just a curiosity question that I've been trying to make.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can print again the whole matrix and check the x,y pair before writing the 0 or the 1

```
for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++) // X
{
     cout << 0;

     for(int y = 0; y < 10; y++) // Y
     {
         //here verify the x,y against the user input
         if(x == xUser && y == yUser)
         {
             cout << " " << 1;
         } else{
             cout << " " << 0;
         }
     }

     cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: hahaha i thought about it but i did an if inside x that checking x is equal to user input x and same with y... didnt think about that :/ thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Get x0 and y0 before the loop using `cin>> x0` and `cin>> y0`.
Inside the loop

```
 if(x == x0 && y==y0)
     cout << " " << 1;
 else
     cout << " " << 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to keep all values in a two dimensional array. Then, play around with the 
values of that array. After than, write the whole array once to the screen.

See the example below :

```
 int matrix[10][10];
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) matrix[i][j]=0;

    matrix[2][3]=1;
    matrix[3][4]=1;
    matrix[4][5]=1;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
       for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
           cout<<matrix[i][j];
       }
           cout << endl;
    }
```